# how to add different condition on same column so as to form a new column in the report based on that condition

Tags: sql

I am working on a business report and the thing is that the business has demanded to create a report that has the different columns that they require.

One of the columns is called `ID_NUMBER` and it's counterpart is `ID_DATE`. So these columns has both old and new data present in it.

For ex : `ID_NUMBER` has both old and new id for a person, and same goes for `ID_DATE`.

So here business has asked to include four columns in the report named `OLD_ID`,`OLD_ID_DATE`,`NEW_ID`,`NEW_ID_DATE`.

I have tried but unable to do so. I am not able to figure out how to extract old and new id number from `ID_COLUMN` and put them in separate new columns, along with their old and new date.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: please provide some example data and show the expected output. Also, which rdbms?

Comment: I feel like a couple of subqueries to isolate new and old records and then joining them on the person is the right solution here. Some sample data and desired results would help out a ton here though so we can fully understand.

Comment: Read this to learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ErayBalkanli Oracle

Comment: NEW_ID   NEW_ID_DATE          OLD_ID           OLD_ID_DATE
00001     5/28/2019             1                 02/18/2018
00002     6/28/2019               2                 8/28/2018 
00004     7/18/2019               4                 7/4/2018                                  so basically this is what i want @JNevill